# I can't get my first else statement to print its output

Tags: python

```
score = int(raw_input('Enter a score: '))

if score >20:
 print 'You achieved an A'

**else:
  if score <=10 and score >= 19:
    print 'You achieved a C'**
```

> Blockquote: If I were enter 13 here I would hope it would output 'You achieved a C', however it outputs nothing.

```
  else:
    if score <10:
     print 'You failed'
```

Comment: I think you got the signs opposite. `if score >=10 and score <= 19`. But if you mention your exact error then we can help you

Comment: a score cannot be less than or equal to ten AND greater than or equal to 19.  it's impossible

Answer (score 3):

This condition

```
if score <=10 and score >= 19
```

will never evaluate to true because there is no such number that is less than 10 and greater than 19.

Perhaps you meant

```
if score >=10 and score <= 19
```

i.e. greater than 10 and less than 19